# Visualizing variability in the size and shape of polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, spatial-statistics, visualisation

I am working with a data set of area restrictions imposed by criminal courts. These restrictions ban a person from entering a demarcated area. These restrictions vary in their size, shape, and location. I would like to describe and, ideally, visualize variability in the size and shape of these restrictions.

My hypothesis is that area restrictions for so called inchoate offenses (public order and drug related offenses, so called "victimless crime") will have much greater variability in their size and shape compared to other offenses.

Would it be possible using PostgreSQL to modify all restrictions associated with a particular offense so that they would all share a common centroid? This would allow a visualization of the effect I am trying to describe.

Comment: I think this is geofencing topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence

Comment: @Mapperz Definitely related, but it sounds like the specific goal here is simply to compare fences with a common offense attribute. What's described is a simple visual comparison - get the centroid of all the fences, and move them all so that those centroids are on a common point; ie stack them all. A mathematical statistic is a bit over my head, though I'm sure some others here could address that. I do note that in some contexts, polygons are 'similar' if they share shapes despite being significantly different sizes. You could look at some geometry statistics - area, number of sides, etc.

Comment: It also seems that because you're looking at *exclusion* fences, rather than containing fences, there might be a higher correlation between numbers of fences and an offender's home range than specifically the shapes and sizes of those fences. In other words, specific offenses such as drugs or crimes involving children may exclude all schools or parks (possibly with a buffer, which again may vary by offense), yet the shapes of the fences themselves are more tied to what they represent than the offense and their numbers in an area aren't necessarily related either. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There is actually a wide and varied literature on comparing polygon shapes - see https://github.com/ianturton/shape-metrics for some code

Comment: +1 It's a great question. It differs from geofencing and, to some extent, from polygon shape metrics in that it focuses on *visualizing* variation of size and shape. I suggest doing some additional standardization beyond matching centroids. In any event, match the principal axes of the polygons, so that two of them with similar shapes will actually appear to line up in the visualization. (This is a matter of rotating them appropriately.) For comparing shapes, regardless of size, consider standardizing the sizes to a unit *area*: this is more stable than most other size-related properties.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions, they are all helpful. I am working to do this in java script now, I haven't been able to figure the problem out in SQL. @whuber thank you in particular for the suggestion re: rotating polygons along principal axes.